# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

First time asking a question. Have gone through similar questions but does not seem to match my inquiry.

Trying to create a calendar with discord bot and getting the favorable "Cannot send an empty message." The bot is able to read the commands and using fs.readFileSync on the specific file returns favorable results.

However, I am trying to use fs.readdir to get the list of files first and then iterate through them with a for loop. The console.log shows favorable results but the bot shows DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message.

```
readFS.js file

var fs = require("fs");

function readPath(){

    fs.readdir('./calendar/', function(err, list){
        if(err) throw err;

        for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            return readFile('./calendar/'+list[i]);
            //return list[i];
        }
    })
}

function readFile(file, err){
    if(err) return err;

    console.log(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file)))
    return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file)));

}

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', reason.stack || reason)
})

module.exports = {
    readFile,
    readPath
}
```

I would like to stay away from promises if possible as they have been kind of hard for me to completely understand. The discord bot is able to discern my arguments with no issue.

```
bot.js file
else if(arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] == "view" && arguments[1] == 'list'){
        receivedMessage.channel.send("Retreiving Calendar!")
        receivedMessage.channel.send(read.readPath())
        //console.log(read.readPath())

    }
```

Actual Error in console:

```
Command received: calendar
Arguments: view,list
{ Title: 'Test Event',
  Description: 'Event for testing the output of JSON',
  StartDate: 'Today',
  StartTime: '3 hours from now',
  LockedTo: 'Guild Only' }
Unhandled Rejection at: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\afrederick\Documents\GitHub\xtreamexe\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (C:\Users\afrederick\Documents\GitHub\xtreamexe\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Hopefully I put enough information.

Answer (score 0):

`read.readPath()` basically returns `void` or `undefined`.

Why? Because you are returning the `readFile()` in the callback function itself. It's not going outside the `fs.readdir` function. So the callback function inside the `readdir` returns the value not `fs.readdir`. Hopefully it makes sense.

First of all, use promises, callbacks are messy and outdated.

But if you want a simple callback solution you have to add another callback to `readPath` and call it from there :-)

```
function readPath(cb){

    fs.readdir('./calendar/', function(err, list){
        if(err) throw err;

        for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            return cb(null, readFile('./calendar/'+list[i]));
            //return list[i];
        }
    })
}
```

**bot.js file**

```
else if(arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] == "view" && arguments[1] == 'list'){
        read.readPath(function(err, data){
            receivedMessage.channel.send("Retreiving Calendar!")
            receivedMessage.channel.send(data)
        })
    }
```

But again, use `Promises` with conjunction with `async/await`, will be easier to understand as well.

Comment: I'll be honest. I have never had success with callbacks either as I would usually get "TypeError: callback is not a function" when used in the manner you have. I appreciate the quick response and actually seeing that my main function call is not getting a response helps greatly. I checked everywhere except there with my console.log.

Comment: I think you should read up about asynchronous functions in node.js, there is no way to throw an error like `cb in not a function` if you know what you are doing. maybe refer javascript.info the resource is pretty good. But honestly if you are using node then you have to use asynchrnous things because that is what node is for. It like a bird who doesn't want to fly.

Comment: I mean,  i have tried many times before to understand callbacks but everytime I have tried to use them, they have not worked for me. I am no developer by any means and trying to understand this as much as I can but some of this stuff is flying over my head. Tried looking at youtube videos and even went so far as to buy some courses on Zenva and Udemy. So I was just hoping that I didn't have to use callbacks or promises.